# Is there a way to install Boto3 with conda or through a tar file?

Tags: docker, boto3, python-3.7

I'm trying to write a docker container for Python 3.7-based scripts and need to use `conda install` to install all the different Python 3.7 packages. Is there a way to `conda install` boto3 or some kind of tar file that can be downloaded?

I've only come across the solution of using the `conda-forge`channel - is this the best way or are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use `anaconda` channel to install `boto3`,

```
conda install -c anaconda boto3
```